# Aerogear core module to start a Android project in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, aerogear

I hope to use aerogear core module and several aerogear modules to create a android mobile client in android studio. I need some guide or help to insert this in to android project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't really a step by step guide on using Android Studio with AeroGear Android, but we do have the Cookbook,  https://github.com/aerogear/aerogear-android-cookbook

If you take the CarStore example, for ummm example,  https://github.com/aerogear/aerogear-android-cookbook/blob/master/CarStore/app/build.gradle#L27 this file shows what you should need to add to your build.gradle file of your app

Since you are using Android Studio you should just be able to add the aerogear android modules to the build.gradle file of your existing app.

Something like

```
dependencies {
....
compile 'org.jboss.aerogear:aerogear-android-core:2.1.0'
compile 'org.jboss.aerogear:aerogear-android-store:2.1.0'
....
}
```

Comment: I saw that. But I need to know the basic setting up like importing modules to existing android app and use those modules.

Comment: well using a module is just like using any other class in Java